# Prolog unify List variables

Tags: prolog

I have an exercise to solve and I have a problem with the display of my program during the solution.

I have facts representing the price per kilo of fruit:

```
price(apple,7).

price(melon,13).

price(banana,8).
```

I need to write a predicate total/2 which determines the total amount of a list of fruits with their weight. Each fruit/weight pair is represented by a two-element list. The first parameter is therefore a list of lists. For example:

```
?- total([[banana,1.5],[apple,0.5]],T).
T=15.5
```

Here is my code:

```
price(apple,7).
price(melon,13).
price(banana,8).


    total([[]],0).
    total([[T1,T2|L],X)):- price(T1,Price), total(L,X1), X is X1+(T2*Price).
```

But my program displays false because probably there is a unification problem. How then can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't even compile. For you to get `false` you must have different code. So, I can fix the code you've posted, but I don't think that's going to help you much. Can you post your real code?

Comment: You can look at the bottom, to the pimple's code, but it doesn't work I don't know why.

Comment: Pimple's code works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first off there's a syntax error in your code. You open a parenthesis and two brackets, but close one bracket and two parenthesis.

```
total([[T1,T2|L],X)) % WRONG
total([[T1,T2]|L],X) % Right
```

Then comes the unification problem: your base case for `total` expects a list containing an empty list (wrong), but in your recursive rule you're passing a list (correct), which eventually gets emptied, call after call.
The error lies in treating `L`, the tail of the "outer" list matched by `[[T1,T2]|L]`, as a list element. It is indeed a list itself, so you don't need to wrap it in brackets.

Fixed, and with prettier names:

```
price(apple, 7).
price(melon, 13).
price(banana, 8).

total([], 0). % Notice the empty inner list has gone

total([[Fr, Wgt] | Tail], T) :- price(Fr, Price),        % Get price for two-element list at the head of the outer list
                                total(Tail, T1),         % Total for the remaining list of two-element lists
                                T is T1 + (Wgt * Price). % Add total for head fruit
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what the base case should be.

Comment: It doesn't work this code, your code I think I've already done like that.

Comment: The base case should be `total([], 0).`. The first version of the answer from two days ago didn't work well, my bad. I mixed my code with yours. With yesterday's update, it should work.

Comment: It always doesn't work when for example I do : 
total([[banana,1.5],[apple,0.5]],X).
It gives me false...
How can I write in a code-like band?

Comment: I don't understand where the problem might be. Maybe your installation requires input in some special form? If you go to https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/pmjQADuF.pl and run your query in the query box (bottom right), don't you get `X = 15.5`?